# Unable to set ajax with php to upload images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, debugging

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='../ajaxImageUpload.php?snid=<?php echo $storeC; ?>' style="clear:both;">
    <div id='imageloadstatus' style='display:none'>
        <img alt="" src="../images/loader.gif"/>
    </div>
    <div id='imageloadbutton'>
        <input type="file" name="photos[]" id="photoimg" accept="image/*" multiple />
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$('#photoimg').die('click').live('change', function() { 
    //$("#preview").html('');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview', 
        beforeSubmit: function() { 
            console.log('ttest');
            $("#imageloadstatus").show();
            $("#imageloadbutton").hide();
        }, 
        success: function(){ 
            console.log('test');
            $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
            $("#imageloadbutton").show();
        }, 
        error: function(){ 
            console.log('xtest');
            $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
            $("#imageloadbutton").show();
        } 
    }).submit();
});
```

I want to pass on the `snid` parameter to that ajaxupload file. The code works perfectly on localhost but not on my hosted server. On the console it says this:

```
[jquery.form] state = complete
POST http://everythingo.com/ajaxImageUpload.php?snid=proshopy 500 (Internal Server Error)
[jquery.form] isXml=false
```

All I get is an empty alert box every time & even echoing the snid from php shows nothing on alert box.

Comment: Can you post the output of your logfile? If you get an 500, you get the reason logged inside your error.log

Comment: I would highly recommend you upgrade your version of jQuery - `die` and `live` were deprecated a ***long*** time ago.

Comment: There are no new errors showing up in my error log. It just shows in the console window & it shouldn't have worked offline if it was really that kind of error/bug.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you provide any sample code related to this functionality?